# Very large JAX-WS deployment issue on Websphere v8.5

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

We have a large application deployed inside a huge war. Inside this package we have about 900 services using javax.jws.WebService, those guys impact the deployment time because when war file is put there, server starts to load any service!
There is any way to do some kind of "lazy load" on that?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.  You can do some things to the ear file to get it to deploy faster but this can get quite involved.  Or you could break it into multiple ear files.  Some tuning options:

Mark modules with no annotations as metadata-complete so they won't be scanned.

Tune which packages are scanned: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/trun_app_reduce_annot.html

Rebuild webservices to include the wsdl with the service to avoid wsdl generation at deploy time.